# Как использовать переменную из одного класса в методе другого класса

Tags: java, классы

Допустим у нас есть класс,  в данном случае это публичный класс Race и у этого класса есть метод setWin в котором инициализируется и возвращается переменная winHorse. Как мне работать с этой переменной в другом публичном классе ,в данном случае в публичном классе Bookmaker. Эти два класса находятся в одном пакете

```java
public class Race {
    public int setWin(){
       int  winHorse = a + (int) (Math.random() * amountHorse);
        System.out.println( "В забеге " + raceNumber + " Выиграла лошадь под номером - " + winHorse );
        return winHorse;
    }

}
```

Второй класс

```java
public class Bookmaker{
public void betWin(){
   System.out.println(" Выиграла лошадь - " + horseWin );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void betWin(Race race) {
  int horseWin = race.setWin();
  System.out.println(" Выиграла лошадь - " + horseWin );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ,  а синтаксически  как это реализовывается, когда мы в параметре после имени класса Race пишем race . Так можно делать в любом случае и как то называется.

Comment: @Артём Это называется "тип и название формального параметра".

Comment: Как-то некрасиво выглядит все это. SetXXX это все же сеттер и было бы лучше сделать winHorse переменной экземпляра и создать для неё сеттер и сеттер. К тому же ваш setxxx каждый раз будет возвращать разное значение. Не думаю, что логикой задачи так должно быть заложено.

Comment: Спасибо , постараюсь исправить. А как быть если в к  примеру в методе betWin мне нужно использовать переменные из двух разных классов